# How to create and set a separate template file for articles in Genesis framework? (Wordpress)

Tags: genesis-theme-framework

I am working in a website which uses Genesis framework (Wordpress).
I would like to have different menus for Homepage and articles,
how do i create a template in Genesis and use it accordingly?

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Thanks,
Balan

Answer (score 1):

**You can use this...**

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php genesis_before_content_sidebar_wrap(); ?>
<div id="content-sidebar-wrap">

    <?php genesis_before_content(); ?>
    <div id="content" class="hfeed">

        <?php genesis_before_loop(); ?>
        <?php genesis_loop(); ?>
        <?php genesis_after_loop(); ?>

    </div><!-- end #content -->
    <?php genesis_after_content(); ?>

</div><!-- end #content-sidebar-wrap -->
<?php genesis_after_content_sidebar_wrap(); ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

---

CHange this line:

```
<?php genesis_loop(); ?>
```

To whatever loop you need whether its single.php, category.php, page.php etc...

Best of luck,
Sagive